# Span and Basis Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V = R4 and W = {( a-2b-c, a+b, b-2c, 2b+c):a, b, c € R}
a.) Find a set S that spans W.
b.) Find a subset S that forms a basis for W.
c.) What is the dimension of W?

I already got the set S where spans{v1,v2,v3,v4}
Where v1= [1,1,0,0], v2=[-2,1,1,2], v3= [-1,0,-2,1] v4=[0,0,0,0]

I tried to answer b and c but my answers were wrong

Comment: What is $v_4{}$?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to check whether the $v_1,v_2,v_3$ you gave are linearly independent.